# Jomsocial error - Notice: JFactory::getUser(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object

Tags: php, joomla3.0, jomsocial

Im getting 2 errors. I saw that Jomsocial had the problem with their own site and fixed it but never posted how. Happens when you go to post an update in jomsocial and it locks up. You refresh the page and get

Error
Sorry, User ID not found.

with the following errors. Then you go login and check the profile and the update was posted fine.

Notice: JFactory::getUser(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "CUser" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php on line 244

Notice: CUser::CUser(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "CUser" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/components/com_community/libraries/user.php on line 52

Answer (score 0):

What version of JomSocial do you use? This issue shouldn't happen